# Time rift episode on Star Trek TNG

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification, time

I remember there was an episode in which the Enterprise was passing through an area of space that had pockets of accelerated time. What I so vividly remember about this episode is that Picard came into a room in which the fruit someone put out was severely molded & old. When he reached for it, he withdrew his hand from the pain of his cells being accelerated as well. Anybody remember this one?

Answer (score 20):

It was [Timescape](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Timescape_(episode)), S6 E25.

An excerpt of the episode:

> Captain Picard and Lieutenant Commanders Data, La Forge, and Counselor Troi are aboard a runabout heading back to rendezvous with the Enterprise. Data turns helm control of the runabout over to the computer and joins Picard, La Forge, and Troi, who are sitting at a table finishing their lunches and discussing their thoughts about the conference. Troi talks about a Ktarian scientist, a Dr. Mizan, who wanted her to join him in "empirical research" on inter-species reproduction. Other than her encounter with Dr. Mizan, Troi was horribly bored at the conference, as there was little opportunity for those attending a seminar to give their views. The lecturer, Professor Wagner, was the only one with freedom to speak.
>
> ...
>
> While working in the cabin, the captain notices something unusual: the fruit on the table (which was fresh minutes ago) is rotten. He innocently reaches with his right hand to touch it, but before he can he screams in agony and pulls his hand immediately away. The three other officers run in to the cabin, reacting to the captain's yell. Picard sits in a chair holding his shaking right hand which has long fingernails that appear to have been growing for several weeks. Troi scans his hand with a tricorder and says that the metabolism in his hand has increased by nearly fifty times. The pain in his hand soon subsides. Data looks at the fruit and performs a scan of the room with his tricorder. The android reports that there is a temporal disturbance, roughly spherical in shape, that intersects with the table. Time within this disturbance passes fifty times more quickly than normal. The disturbance reaches out to seventeen meters in space – covering the starboard nacelle, explaining why the runabout's supply of antimatter was drained. A final look at the fruit shows that it has completely disintegrated into dust.

And the hand?  Here:

[image]